# Is there a way to add Apple remote support to a website using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like how you can use the Apple remote in front row and i know other apps on the mac support it. I am wondering if Web Apps could support it via Javascript? I had a idea for a tv type interface. I would have it understand the Apple remote and also understand up down left right enter back. I know from working on a slideshow app before that left and right keys have a number that is passed when pressed. Does the Apple Remote pass anything or how could i make web apps understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this link:
http://www.machoe.com/1602/enhance-your-apple-remote-with-mira.html

i haven't tried it myself, but i think you should be able to map the buttons on the remote to keystrokes. all you need to do then is to listen to these keystrokes in your application.

Comment: The App said it cost money. :( I kinda wanted something free... But maybe mapping buttons is the only thing Apple allows.